# Want calendar to be responder of UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I am creating an app in that app in which i'm displaying date in UITextView. And that text should be  selected from UIDatepicker , But instead of UIDatepicker i want to display calendar when user begin editing textview and select date from calendar and that date will be show in textview. how can i do that? does apple allow that? code would be better.

Comment: just look into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940875/how-to-show-calendar-instead-of-using-uidatepicker-in-iphone

Comment: in osx no code is better. I am trying for ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For display popover Calendar you can use [PMCalendar](https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar) and [OCCalendar](https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar) link.
this will display calender like this :

[image]

And this :

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. it works fine. but still keyboard display when i touch textview. any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Use below two delegates method

```
 -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
 //type required code here to start date picket.

 -(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
 //type required code here when user done with editing
```

Comment: thanx for reply. but i know this delegate methods. i want to know about calender.

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate method

```
    -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
     //show the calendar
}
```

In the calendar's action method, set the `textView.text` as selected date

Comment: thanx for reply. but i know this delegate methods. i want to know about calender.

Comment: What do you mean by calenadr? the UIDatePicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as :

```
NSString *stringDate=[self.textField text];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromText=[dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

[self.datePicker setDate:dateFromText];
```

**NOTE: you need to validate the date entered by user should be in a specific format.** 
Call the above codes from a button action or from a delegate.

Comment: but i want date from calender not from date picker

Comment: i want a calender that be frirst respondar for textview

Comment: sorry no idea about ios calender :(