# Recording and saving user date of birth when user tap on the text field

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

In my first app using Swift 3, on the profile screen, user can enter his date of birth.

User taps a text field, upon tapping UI DatePicker is shown. My problem is that Date Picker is only showing day and time. I would like to have a calendar where user can select his date of birth and then that date of birth shows in text field from where later it will be saved in database. I came across many answers here but they are based mostly upon the Date Picker not on the calendar.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userDateofBirthTextField.delegate = self
}


func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {


    let datePicker = UIDatePicker( )
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

    datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -16, to: Date())

    userDateofBirthTextField.inputView = datePicker // selected date should show in text field
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    textField.inputView = datePicker
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    userDateofBirthTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


func closekeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    closekeyboard()
}
```

Comment: why did you assign data picker as input view of userDateofBirthTextField in datePickerChanged method ?

Comment: As I am not sure, how do I show the selected date in the text field. Please recommend any solutions

Comment: There is no ready made solution which will convert UIDatePicker to calender view. Try below link and find useful links. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940977/8170770

Comment: move your code of `datePickerChanged` to `viewDidLoad`. Then on click of textfield your datepicker will open. You need to learn basic. Find some good tutorial and read it!

Comment: If you want a date picker that shows just the date, then set the date picker's `datePickerMode` property as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can changed as below.

**In ViewDidLoad**

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -16, to: Date())
    userDateofBirthTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    textField.inputView = datePicker
```

**Selector method**

```
 func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
              let formatter = DateFormatter()
         formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy mm dd"   
             userDateofBirthTextField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
        }
```